# How to select records of same id and group it to one record?

Tags: mysql, database, select, jdbc, records

I have a table with column 'ID','Plans','Type','Type_id'

```
ID | Type    | Plans       | Type_id
_____________________________________
1  | Package | Gold        | 3
1  | Package | Silver      | 2
1  | Package | Platinum    | 4
1  | Channel | HollywoodOn | 200
```

I want some output like this:

```
ID | Type    | Plans       
_____________________________________
1  | Package | Gold,Silver,Platinum      
1  | Channel | HollywoodOn
```

Please help Guys.Thanks.
P.S: Sorry for the stupid format i used to post.I am a noob at stack overflow.

Comment: Think of using `group_concat` and `group by`

Comment: Thanks Reddy It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT id,TYPE,GROUP_CONCAT(plans SEPARATOR ', ') AS Plans FROM plans GROUP BY TYPE